# Deep Linking приложений из Play Market

Tags: android, react-native, deeplink

Пытаюсь сделать переходы из своего приложения прямо в приложение разработчика. Даже желательно с вводом данных в инпут. Uber имеет эту возможность и я сделал это вот так:

```
uber://?action=setPickup&pickup[latitude]=${pickup.lat}&pickup[longitude]=${pickup.lng}&dropoff[latitude]=${dropoff.lat}&dropoff[longitude]=${dropoff.lng}
```

Остальные приложения, такие как Bolt (Taxify), Uklon, OnTaxi открываются только по неймингу. Ввод данных не знаю как сделать, так как документации у них нет, они не такие огромные как Uber.

По этим ссылкам на Android напрямик в приложение не заходит. Главный вопрос: Как сделать Deep Link хотя бы в приложение на Андроид (без ввода данных). Как найти этот URL-schema приложения.

Также не переходит в приложение Бонд на iOS. С остальными неймингами угадал, а тут подобрать не могу. Где их находить?

Comment: в манифесте приложения)) продолжайте гадать у вас хорошо получается;)

Comment: @IvanVovk спасибо) Но всё же, разве у меня есть доступ к манифесту каждого приложения? К своему приложению допустим информацию окей, а где взять файл других приложений?

Comment: У вас есть доступ к любому установленному на устройстве APK. А содержимое в читабельном виде можно посмотреть, например, через приложение "Dexplorer" или подобное (поищите в маркете).

Comment: @woesss Спасибо, попробую.